# Find and replace broken links

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

I've taken over a massive MOSS 2007 project, nearly 2000 pages deep. During initial development, the previous developers used a testing URL to test particular sections of their web parts:

http://wwwtest.ad.domain

This went live with the application and is now causing issues with some of the links as the DNS entry was removed from the client's front-end, so I need to rename all of these to the actual link of the web site.

I've read up on how to do this effectively, through SP Designer but this did not work for me. I've found several tools ($ of course) but sure there must be a way through a C# command-let or something. I haven't found any code online that points me in the right direction.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used PowerShell in the past to iterate through the object model and seek out links with a particular prefix (ie: http://oldurl) and either remove the link or update if necessary. That stuff is a bit harder in 2007 (PowerShell is a little more limited, though it still should be possible).

Comment: I've been too lazy to actually write a command-let to itterate my site structure. As this is a pretty deep site, and we're still finding issue, might as well just do it. Thanks webdes03

Answer (score 1):

there is also one by www.qipoint.com for sp2010 to report on broken links, its free

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xenu for broken links for many years and it is free. Just click here for more information at this link http://www.seomoz.org/blog/xenu-link-sleuth-more-than-just-a-broken-links-finder
You can create xml reports, excel or text reports, sitemaps, missing alt tags reports and so on. The only disadvantage is fact, that you can't replace listed links...